# Simple.Data does not recognize my new table

Tags: c#, sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, simple.data

We have a web application which creates a new table in SQL Server during a particular administration function.  When I query this table using Simple.Data in an other part of the application I receive an

```
unresolvableobjectexception
```

as if Simple.Data cannot see this new table.

I have confirmed this is not a database permissions issue.

The behaviour I can see is that if I recycle the application pool then Simple.Data starts to work.  This would indicate that a singleton/cache has been refreshed.

Is anyone aware of a mechanism to update the Simple.Data cache through code to achieve the same affect as the recycle.

I am using the

```
FindAllBy
```

syntax in Simple.Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I discovered that there is a method on the adapter object which will clear the cache and this gets reinitialized automatically. Just call

```
DatabaseSchema.ClearCache();
```

Also Mark Rendle pointed me to the method which does the same thing

```
Database.ClearAdapterCache();
```